# Openimaj and LiblinearAnnotator "train()" method arguments

Tags: java, openimaj

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.openimaj.org/tutorial/classification101.html) here and have a question regarding this:

```
LiblinearAnnotator<Record<FImage>, String> ann = new LiblinearAnnotator<Record<FImage>, String>(
                    extractor, Mode.MULTICLASS, SolverType.L2R_L2LOSS_SVC, 1.0, 0.00001);
ann.train(splits.getTrainingDataset());
```

Now the `train()` method as per [documentation](http://www.openimaj.org/apidocs/org/openimaj/ml/annotation/linear/LiblinearAnnotator.html#train%28org.openimaj.data.dataset.GroupedDataset%29) it can take a `GroupedDataset` as argument. I am passing a `VFSGroupDataset` with multiple classes and it is failing although the `VFSGroupDataset` extends `GroupedDataset`.

Maybe I am a bit confused, but why is it failing?

ANSWER: Use 1.4-SNAPSHOT Version

Comment: Can you try with the latest development version of OpenIMAJ (1.4-SNAPSHOT)? I think there was a problem with the typing of the generics in the method signature that got fixed a while ago.

Comment: Ok thanks! I will give it a go and let you know!

Comment: @Jon Where can I find the latest version? Github points up until 1.3.1...

Comment: Oh ok! I had to use this repo, http://snapshots.openimaj.org/ ! It works now! Thanks!